# Hanafuda Hat Winter Bash

Tags: discussion, winter-bash, winter-bash-2020

Regarding the Hanafuda Hat, this is what it says:

> Post 5 questions or answers during Winter Bash that receive a positive
> score.

Should we post 5 questions or answers in one day? And can these posts be in different Stack Exchange websites to count?

https://winterbash2020.stackexchange.com/hanafuda

Answer (score 4):

It can be either questions or answers; it just has to be a *post* that is positively received (i.e. upvoted and not downvoted).

The posts do have to be on the same site to qualify; the hat is per-site. You can earn it once on every site - for instance, I've earned it here on Meta.SE, but not other sites on the network.

They do not have to be in the same day; the hat would have said so if they were. They just all have to be posted during *Winter Bash*.

Answer (score 3):

> Should we post 5 questions or answers in one day?

Not necessarily.

> And can these posts be in different Stack Exchange websites to count?

No. The hats are specific to sites, so all the posts need to be on the same site for them to count towards the hat trigger.

Answer (score 1):

I can confirm what the other answerers said, I got the Hanafuda hat on Stack overflow. I answered more than 5 questions through out this winter bash, and got it by having 1 or more upvotes on 5 answers.

[image]